# New To C -- Making changes to the program produces same printed statements?

Tags: c

Even when I make changes to a program in C in VS Code, the same output is produced, as if the changes are not being read.

For example, take a "hello world" C program.

On the first run of the program, "hello world" is printed on the screen just like expected. Great!

However, even when I make changes to the code on the screen and then re-run the program, the same "hello world" is printed to the screen every time. For example, if I change my statement to:

printf("hello\n");

"hello world" is still printed just like in the first run. What's going on?

Comment: Did you save the `.c` file after applying the changes? Did you recompile the program before executing it?

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. I was trying to save the file with control s and, quite literally, the s key on my keyboard is just broken. I saved it on screen and that fixed my whole problem. Thanks!

Comment: *Well, now I feel stupid. ...* Welcome to the wonderful world of writing code - that won't be the last time you feel like you did (or wrote) something stupid.  There are two types of programmers: those who write buggy code full of stupid mistakes, and liars.

Comment: It is so much better to have a simple solution to your problem and feel stupid than feel validated by having a real bug to deal with.

Comment: I promise that won't be the worst reason of an error you will face in the future. :D